# extjs : synchronize two grid panels

Tags: extjs

I have 2 grid panels, one is in main window and other panel(clone of 1st grid panel) is popup of same window.

I want to synchronize both panels in a way so that if we sort one panel it should automatically sort another grid panel with same column sort and if client filter applied on one it should reflect another grid panel.

I am opening up 2nd grid panel from first panel's header double click.

**Code** :

```
    headerEntry.on('dblclick', function () { me.maximizeWindow(me, this, parentPanel) });//It will open 2nd grid panel from first panel's header double click.

    maximizeWindow: function (parentWindow, header, parentPanel) {
            var parentHeight = parentWindow.getHeight();
            var parentWidth = parentWindow.getWidth();
            var height = ((parentHeight - 100) / parentHeight) * 100;
            var width = ((parentWidth - 100) / parentWidth) * 100;
            var win = Ext.widget('window', {
                title: '',
                height: height + '%',
                width: width + '%',
                layout: 'fit',
                id: parentPanel + "_Child",
                itemId: 'dashboardWin' + parentWindow.customParams.dashboardId,
                minimizable: true,
                constrain: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                modal: true,
                header: false,
                anchor: '100%',
                x: parentWindow.getX() + 50,
                floating: true,
                closable: false,
                constrainTo: parentWindow,
                monitorResize: true,
                renderTo: parentWindow.getEl(),
                maskClickAction: 'hide',
                listeners: {
                    boxready: function () {
                        var win = this;
                        Ext.EventManager.on(document, 'keyup', function (e) {
                            var keyValue = e.getKey();
                            if (keyValue == 27) {  //on escape button it will close popup grid and first grid should reflect with changes done in 2nd grid.     
}
// rest code
```

Comment: use the same grid with two different names, no id... events should be bound in a controller.

Comment: tried, but not working..